# How to redraw a DOM element after zoom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, repaint, redraw

I am currently using [zoom.js](http://lab.hakim.se/zoom-js/) to zoom-in on some SVG shapes that I have drawn in HTML. Consider the following snippet:

```
<div id="circle">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

With the event handler:

```
$('#circle').bind('click', function(event) {
   zoom.in({ 
    element: document.querySelector( '#circle' ) 
   });
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

After zooming in, the SVG shape's borders appears quite pixelated, and it looks like the SVG shape is not being re-drawn after the zoom. The same behaviour seems to occur with all DOM elements (e.g. a DIV filled with a color, or a text element). However, when I look at the website linked above, the text elements seem to get redrawn after zooming has occurred. I'm having trouble understanding why it is not redrawn in my case.

Edit: I have also tried putting the SVG element in a separate file and including it, as such:

```
<embed src="circle.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
```

The same problem occurs using this method.

Edit 2: I have tried to set the element's display to "none" and resetting back to "block" after zooming in - some posts seemed to suggest this would force a redraw - but the element still appears pixelated after becoming visible again:

```
$('#circle').css('display', 'none').css('display', 'block');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) to draw my SVG shapes instead of plain old HTML/XML. For a reason that remains a mystery to me, the bug that spurred the question does not occur with the shapes it draws.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer for the redrawing issue remains a mystery to me, why not use the same type of method they used to invoke?

```
document.querySelector('#circle').addEventListener( 'click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  zoom.in( { element: event.target } );
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work! Still those nasty pixels come and bug me.

Comment: Damn. I didn't think so, but at least we gave it a shot. I did some more digging and come to find out it looks like there might be problems with this in FireFox and IE7/8, Safari should display properly. I was checking the bug report, and it seems like the quick fix is to include the svg as an external file through the <object> parameter instead of writing inline <svg>. Give that a go.

Comment: Thanks for the idea... I'm afraid the problem remains, though. And apparently, Chrome doesn't print embedded SVG files!

Comment: That's rough. Sorry bud. I'm out of ideas. If I come across something else I'll post it through. Good luck in the meantime, though!